# Updating an interval variable on screen in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**In the head section:**

```
var countdownTimer;  <br/>
countdownTimer = 45;  <br/>

function makeCountdown() {  <br/>
   countdownTimer = countdownTimer - 1;  <br/>

}

setInterval(makeCountdown, 1000);
<br/><br/>
```

**In the body section of the page:**

```
document.write(countdownTimer);<br/>

function updateCountdown() {  <br/>
   document.replace(countdownTimer);  <br/>

}
<br/><br/>
setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);


<br/><br/>
```

I've checked in the browser console and the countdownTimer variable goes down each second, but where I'm struggling is on how to update the variable on the page in real time.

I've had a long look and I can't find anything here or elsewhere online that can help me out, I'm also fairly new to javascript. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: `document.replace` is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little addition to Rayon's answer. To stop countdown when timer reach 0

```js
    var timer=45;
    var intervalId;
    function countdown(){ 
        $('#elem').text(timer);  
        if(timer==0){
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        timer--;
    }
    intervalId=setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="elem"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you both very kindly, I now have a great countdown timer and a renewed enthusiasm for finishing my first game.

Comment: Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 2):

- Make changes to the Element rather than `document` itself
- There is no `replace` method for `document`
- There is no point having 2 intervals if duration is identical

Note: Make sure you place `script` as last child of `body` or else, DOM api will try toa ccess the element before `DOM` is ready which will return `null` result for `document.getElementById('elem')`

```js
var countdownTimer;
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
countdownTimer = 45;

function makeCountdown() {
  countdownTimer = countdownTimer - 1;
  elem.textContent = countdownTimer;
}
setInterval(makeCountdown, 1000);
elem.textContent = countdownTimer;
```

```html
<span id='elem'><span>
```

Comment: thank you so much! I just needed an example to get my head around how it all works. this makes perfect sense to me and will make my development in JS a whole lot easier!

Comment: I've tried it, and the result is that there is no variable visible on the screen within the span tags?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Comment: Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`))